# Criando um CDN - content delivery network

Tags: php, apache, servidor, cdn

*Wikipedia*

> Sistema de computadores interligados em rede através da Internet, que cooperam de modo transparente para fornecer conteúdo.
>
> CDN são geralmente implantados em vários locais. Os benefícios incluem a redução dos custos de largura de banda, melhorando os tempos de carregamento da página, ou aumentando disponibilidade global de conteúdo.

---

*Baboo*

> Uma CDN é uma rede de distribuição de informação e dados que permite fornecer conteúdo na web de forma rápida para vários usuários, independentemente de onde essa pessoa se encontra. O que o sistema faz é distribuir um mesmo conteúdo em diversos servidores, para direcionar esses dados de acordo com a proximidade de servidor do usuário.
>
> O serviço funciona como um cache dos arquivos não dinâmicos do site, em diferentes datacenters de localidades dispersas em todo o mundo.

---

*[(Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929037/1244639)*

> CDN é simplesmente uma rede de servidores que replicam seus arquivos binários de modo que eles são servidos a partir de locais geograficamente próximos. CDN é simplesmente - um bando de "discos" que estão espalhados por todo o mundo em diferentes datacenters. Você envia o seu arquivo a um desses discos - e depois diz de onde seus clientes estão vindo. Ela irá então copiar o mesmo arquivo para outros discos que estão mais perto de seus clientes.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>**Distribuição de servidor único *vs* CDN** (wikipedia)</sub>

---

### Dito isso, vamos às questões.

Tem um bom tempo que venho pesquisando sobre CDNs para um projeto com grande demanda de conteúdo estático. Não queria recorrer a nenhum *CDN Free*, tão pouco contratar um *akamai*. Então pensei em me aprofundar no assunto para pesar o custo benefício de montar algo próprio.

1. Supondo que eu escolha um DC no Brasil e um nos EUA para um CDN nas Américas, a identificação da requisição para buscar o DC mais próximo é feita no server, ou no PHP?
2. Feito o upload de uma imagem, ela é replicada instantaneamente para os DC ou somente quando houver demanda local?
3. Apache e Linux bastam ou há necessidade de instalação de outras ferramentas próprias para um CDN?

Tendo meu domínio principal com links para `www.my-cdn.com`, neste posso ter o PHP trabalhando com o GEOIP para saber a localização da requisição, mas como demandar o DC correto? Me parece que dessa forma o processo é mais dispendioso. **Há ferramentas próprias?**

---

Não espero um tutorial, só uma luz sobre alguns pontos. Eu realmente já procurei bastante, mas tudo é muito superficial, não encontrei nada que se aprofunde na criação de um CDN, a maioria explica como funciona, ou explana as diferenças entre CDN e um Cloud.

Comment: Devia ter como sinalizar esta pergunta como -> **Pergunta esta muito boa e merece uma recompensa.** +1.

Comment: Concordo com o @DenerCarvalho. Nem teve resposta e eu já aprendi o que é um CDN só com o texto da pergunta. Tomara que receba respostas tão boa quanto a pergunta, também ficarei no aguardo.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que a resposta da primeira é é feita no server "mais próximo" e não no PHP, mas é algo realmente que não entendo :/ - Grande pergunta +1

Comment: @renan, fiz uma update na questão demonstrando o uso do PHP com o GEOIP para a localização, por isso coloquei a tag da linguagem. Mas creio que as respostas sejam menos tendenciosas à linguagem.

Comment: O "buraco é mais embaixo". Dê uma pesquisada em BGP4 (Border Gateway Protocol). Uma CDN "de verdade" trabalha em nível de protocolo de roteamento, mesmo antes de chegar no servidor. De acordo com o lugar de onde vem a conexão, é definido quem vai atender a requisição.

Comment: O DNS tem um papel crucial na implementação de uma CDN (https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/11/29/how-content-delivery-networks-cdns-work/). Parece interessante: http://www.fromdev.com/2011/06/create-cdn-content-delivery-network.html

Comment: @cantoni lembrando que a rota pode ser resolvida em nível de IP também.

Comment: @PapaCharlie eu não entendo como funciona, mas o comentário do Bacco parece ser a resposta da primeira, só não sei como funciona, mas vou acompanhar, até favoritei a pergunta :D

Comment: Tem um brinquedo aqui interessante: https://stat.ripe.net/widget/bgplay#w.resource=104.24.99.83 - Peguei um IP do CloudFlare, pra vcs verem quantos caminhos diferentes tem. Comparem com uma hospedagem simples. Embaixo tem as linhas do tempo, vocês podem acompanhar as mudanças todas de rota em determinados períodos. Isso aí, de maneira simplificada, é um gráfico de como os sistemas sabem os caminhos entre sí para trocas de dados.

Comment: Conceitos importantes pra começar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol

Comment: Espero que com o _bounty_ na postagem alguém lembre de falar de Anycast, que apesar de mais complicado de implementar, funciona independente do DNS, como grandes redes como CloudFlare fazem. Pra quem não sabe o que é, é o **mesmo IP** em todos os lugares, e no roteamento de borda é escolhida a rede mais "próxima". Funciona mesmo se, por exemplo, alguém do Brasil ou de Portugal estiver usando DNS do Google ou OpenDNS.

Comment: @PapaCharlie https://anuragbhatia.com/networking/different-cdn-technologies-dns-vs-anycast-routing/

Comment: @Bacco Valeu por mais uma referência, vou garimpas todos os links - tem material pra caramba, vai dar uma clareada legal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pense num CDN como mais um tipo de cache que visa diminuir o tempo que o usuário espera por algum recurso, geralmente imagens, estilos, fontes e scripts, mas não se limitando a estes.

Em geral, os recursos que ficam num CDN (ou qualquer outro cache) devem ser estáticos, ou seja, não mudam, pelo menos por um período de tempo.

Um site ou sistema web pode ter vários níveis de cache. Vamos ver alguns:

## Servindo conteúdo estático

Suponha que você tem um blog em Wordpress ou algum sistema que gera páginas dinamicamente de acordo com a URL e parâmetros. Suponha que devido ao conteúdo ser grande, seu blog está demorando 10 segundos para carregar uma página.

A primeira coisa que você pode fazer é evitar que seja necessário gerar a página novamente a cada requisição. O esforço para fazer isso depende do tipo de conteúdo.

Se partes do site, tal como propagandas, variam a cada requisição, você pode isolar isso carregando este conteúdo de forma assíncrona ou colocando-o num `iframe`. O restante da página pode ser armazenado em memória ou em arquivos no disco.

Uma estratégia simples para se fazer isso é usar um proxy como o [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). Basicamente ele fica entre o usuário e o servidor. Na primeira requisição a um recurso, ele pede ao servidor para gerar aquela página, como se fosse um acesso normal. Ele, então, salva o conteúdo recebido do servidor e devolve ao cliente. Nas demais requisições ao mesmo recurso, ele simplesmente devolve o que foi salvo antes.

Este mecanismo permite aumentar em várias ordens de magnitude a carga que um servidor suporta. Ele ataca principalmente o tempo de processamento do servidor, que neste caso iria incluir a execução de centenas de scripts PHP e dezenas de acessos ao banco de dados.

## Evitando acessos frequentes ao banco de dados

Continuando no exemplo do blog, o problema é que no primeiro acesso a uma página, o usuário ainda leva 10 segundos para ver o resultado.

Uma das causas comuns para a demora da geração de uma página num sistema web é que ele sempre precisa carregar toda a informação do banco de dados novamente.

A primeira recomendação para resolver isto é evitar ler a mesma informação mais de uma vez do banco. Um efeito colateral da modularização dos sistemas é que muitas vezes classes ou scripts diferentes solicitam a mesma informação várias vezes e isso vai até o banco de dados.

A forma de resolver isso é criar um tipo de cache de requisição, onde informações já lidas são reusadas até o fim da requisição.

A segunda coisa que se pode fazer é estender o cache de requisição para ser reusado entre requisições no caso de informações que mudam pouco. Por exemplo, num sistema que lida com galerias de imagens, as categorias tendem a não mudar com tanta frequência, então você pode colocar a lista de categorias num cache e invalidar o cache somente quando o usuário ou administrador fizer mudanças.

O cache de itens do banco de dados é geralmente feito em memória e, dependendo da escala de distribuição, pode usar um cache distribuído.

Esta abordagem diminui o tempo de processamento do servidor para gerar uma saída.

## Evitando requisições desnecessárias

Nas duas abordagens anteriores, tentamos diminuir ao máximo o tempo de resposta do servidor, na primeira requisição e também nas requisições subsequentes.

Entretanto, a latência até os servidor pode ser um grande problema se ainda houverem muitos recursos carregadas numa página.

### Empacotando recursos de forma eficiente

Se você tem muitos scripts e estilos, considere minificá-los e agrupá-los em arquivos maiores. Imagens pequenas também podem ser agrupadas numa imagem maior em *sprites* exibidos com estilos CSS específicos.

A maioria dos navegadores limita os downloads concorrentes a não mais do que meia dúzia, portanto de você tiver, por exemplo suns 15 scripts, 10 estilos e mais 30 imagens, tudo isso vai ser enfileirado e baixado em cascata.

Porém, se você juntar cada tipo de recurso em arquivos arquivos maiores, isso vai diminuir o tempo total de download.

Note que com HTTP/2 isso não será tanto verdade, porque ele vai suportar transporte multiplexado de vários recursos em uma só conexão, além de compactar os cabeçalhos, diminuindo o overhead. Portanto, verifique se o seu servidor tem suporte a HTTP/2 antes de criar *batches* de recursos.

### Fazendo bom uso do cache do navegador

Outro problema que geralmente é ignorado é quando não se faz bom uso do cache do browser. Páginas e recursos que não mudam devem ser configurados para serem cacheados por bastante tempo.

Imagine que usamos a versão 1.7.1. do jQuery no blog. Podemos configurar o cache dele para durar "eternamente", isto é, nunca expirar. Se quisermos mudar a versão do jQuery, basta servir a biblioteca com outra URL na página, por exemplo:

> /js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js

Portanto, se os recursos tiverem a versão incluída na URL e o cache estiver configurado corretamente, o usuário só vai precisar carregar os arquivos novamente quando eles efetivamente mudarem.

O mesmo pode ser feito com imagens se você configurar a URL das imagens com algum padrão baseado, talvez, na data de upload ou alteração das mesmas.

Enfim, é importante pensar em cada recurso que a sua página baixa no navegador e definir uma política de cache. Quanto mais você conseguir tornar estático e fazer cache "infinito", melhor.

### Usando cache de terceiros

Se a sua página usa bibliotecas comuns como o jQuery, você pode considerar servi-las usando um CDN externo gratuito.

O Google, por exemplo, [hospeda várias bibliotecas comuns](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#libraries) e ao usá-las você aproveita os arquivos já em cache se o usuário acessou algum site que usa as mesmas bibliotecas e as mesmas versões.

Além disso, o navegador verifica que esses arquivos estão em outro domínio e pode aumentar o número de conexões simultâneas para download.

De quebra, você economiza banda e processamento no seu servidor.

Eu sei que você mencionou que não queria usar CDNs gratuitos, mas neste caso não é o mesmo que usar um CDN qualquer. Dificilmente você vai conseguir um uptime maior do que um CDN como esse do Google, por exemplo.

## Chegando mais próximo do usuário

Supondo que aplicamos todos os passos acima, o blog deve estar rápido como uma bala. (Eu sei, porque fiz tudo isso no meu).

Entretanto, usuários que fazem a primeira requisição do outro lado do mundo ainda tem algumas dificuldades para carregar as páginas mais pesadas ou, neste caso, pode ser que algumas imagens grandes demoram para serem baixadas.

Além disso, às vezes o usuário pressiona F5 e o browser decide fazer uma requisição HTTP `HEAD` para verificar se os recursos mudaram e o carregamento da página fica lento porque até isso demora.

Bem, é aqui que você precisa começar a pensar em geolocalização, isto é, em colocar um servidor mais perto do seu cliente.

### Distribuindo seu sistema

Uma abordagem para diminuir a latência de forma geral, não só de recursos estáticos, é simplesmente colocar uma cópia do sistema perto do cliente.

O problema dessa abordagem é que nem sempre é fácil dividir o banco de dados, principalmente se o conteúdo é compartilhado entre todos os usuários, como numa rede social.

No caso de um blog, você poderia simplesmente criar nós em diferentes locais e sincronizar o conteúdo nos nós *slave* baseando-se num nó mestre, por exemplo.

No entanto, esta abordagem geralmente requer mudanças na arquitetura do sistema de forma geral.

### Usando CDNs

Finalmente chegamos ao ponto.

Se você concluir de que boa parte do tempo de carregamento da página se dá no download de recursos estáticos (ou que poderiam ser estáticos, ou que podem ser versionados variando a URL), então uma boa estratégia seria distribuir esses recursos para perto do usuário, usando servidores em diferentes localidades, enquanto o sistema principal ainda poderia estar centralizado.

Imaginemos que o blog tem mais acessos no Brasil e no Japão, sendo o sistema hospedado no Brasil.

Se pensarmos num CDN como uma simples rede de distribuição de conteúdo, podemos então conceber um cache no Japão para armazenar as imagens para que os usuários de olhos puxados experimentem a mesma velocidade de download que os mamelucos daqui.

Vamos dividir a estrutura de nosso CDN em infraestrutura de rede e um servidor HTTP simples.

Uma infraestrutura de rede poderia usar uma implementação da metodologia [Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast). Basicamente, esta tecnologia permite rotear uma requisição para o nó mais perto da rede. Assim, poderíamos servir apenas uma URL para cada imagem e o servidor que receberia a requisição depende da localização do cliente.

Já no servidor HTTP simples, precisamos apenas de um Apache e uma cópia das imagens que serão servidas. Nenhum mistério.

O problema está em como colocar as imagens nos dois servidores HTTP que ficam no Brasil e no Japão.

A forma *lazy* de fazer isto é colocar um script no servidor Apache que verifica se a imagem existe localmente naquele nó. Caso exista, basta servir a imagem. Se não existir, faz uma requisição ao sistema e salva localmente.

O problema desta abordagem é que regredimos o desempenho parcialmente:
a primeira requisição ainda vai demorar muito. A vantagem é que a imagem que um usuário acessa fica no cache daquela região para todos os demais usuários acessarem. Isso pode ser vantajoso no caso de um blog, mas se cada usuário tende a acessar imagens diferentes, o ganho será mínimo.

A alternativa é ser agressivo e, cada vez que um usuário fizer o upload de uma imagem, você distribui o conteúdo na sua rede distribuidora de conteúdos. O resultado é que temos a melhor experiência para os usuários de cada região, quando eles tentam visualizar as imagens.

Em contrapartida, você cria uma dificuldade para quem envia as imagens. Agora a requisição precisa esperar a sincronização entre os servidores e os criadores de conteúdo é quem vão sofrer.

Você pode pensar em fazer isto de forma assíncrona, mas isso também significa que alguém acessando uma página no momento de um upload pode ver um link quebrado porque a imagem ainda não foi parar no CDN mais próximo dela.

E o problema só aumentaria ao escalar sua rede de conteúdos para mais localidades.

Uma terceira alternativa seria implementar as duas primeiras, isto é, fazer o cache de forma agressiva, mas sincronizar individualmente a imagem caso dela não encontrar o nó que recebeu a requisição.

### CDN caseiro?

Por tudo isso, eu realmente quero desencorajar você a criar, sua própria solução de CDN.

Se você tiver pouco tráfego, CDN provavelmente não vale a pena. Se você tiver muito tráfego, pagar um bom CDN será uma das menores preocupações.

Pense no tempo desperdiçado em configurar toda essa infraestrutura e ainda no tempo gasto para lidar com problemas de sincronização durante o upload.

## Considerações

Eu escrevi tudo isso porque na maioria das vezes você pode resolver o seu problema de performance, alcançando um desempenho aceitável, simplesmente fazendo um *tuning* no seu servidor e/ou no seu sistema.

Por outro lado, muitas vezes vemos no CDN um tipo de "salvador da pátria", um jeito mágico, rápido e fácil de ganhar desempenho com pouco esforço e isto não é verdade na maioria dos casos.

Claro que a decisão de criar ou contratar um CDN, ou mesmo decidir não usar nenhum, cabe a cada tipo de sistema e ao uso que é feito dele. Espero que essas informações ajudem a que os leitores possam tomar decisões melhores para cada situação.

Comment: Já faço uso de *sprites* e cache para arquivos estáticos, inclusive alguns itens do BD como você mencionou. Ainda não terminei de ler tudo, vou ler e reler com calma... Essa resposta foi uma aula!

Answer (score 5):

1 - A escolha de servidor será feita antes mesmo da sua aplicação ser acionada. O responsável é um elemento de rede (ex: proxy reverso) ou mesmo pelo DNS (resposta 3). Você pode entender a rede de CDN como uma camada anterior à infra da sua aplicação.

2 - Vai parecer uma resposta vazia, mas "depende". Há implementações passivas e ativas. Sendo que as ativas (replicação instantânea) tendem a apresentar melhores resultados.

3 - Você precisará definir o roteador das requisições. Aquele que saberá qual servidor está mais próximo do requerente. Normalmente isso é feito com um servidor DNS que se vale de uma tabela de geolocalização de IPs.

Comment: +1, só uma ressalva: depender de DNS não é eficaz. A geolocalização do DNS não tem relação direta com a geolocalização do cliente final, e há casos em que a resolução é feita em cascata. Ex: se alguém for analisar minhas requisições, vai ver os IPs do OpenDNS na maior parte dos casos, que não guardam relação com a posiçao geográfica de onde estou requisitando os dados. O DNS serve apenas como uma camada auxiliar. Além disso, tem provedores que repassam a requisição para DNS de terceiros, complicando mais a determinação geográfica. O ideal mesmo seria rotear o endereço nas bordas entre os ASs.

Answer (score 5):

CDNs são mais complexos do que um mero redirecionamento baseado em um servidor PHP. Até porque, se levar em conta a latência que o servidor demandará para tomar a decisão, já vai estar na verdade atrapalhando o objetivo.

CDNs de verdade, como um CloudFire ou Akamai, possuem uma estrutura muito mais robusta, já em nível de datacenter e roteamento, ou seja, é briga de gente grande.

Acho louvável a intenção de não depender de terceiros para poder servir conteúdo, afinal é assim que surgem novas idéias. A idéia de roteamento via PHP pode ser uma alternativa interessante para redundância ou balanceamento de carga. Também precisaríamos levar em conta dados reais mais concretos sobre qual vai ser a sua demanda, assim podemos fazer contas e ver se realmente do que seu propósito carecerá de tecnologia e qual custo gerará.

Sem querer desanimar, considere que dependendo do tamanho da demanda, um CloudFire poderá sair mais em conta já com os recursos prontos. Caso tenha mais dados, teremos satisfação em lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

## Características e requisitos básicos de um CDN

Um CDN pode além de manter uma cópia de conteúdos estáticos, podem ser utilizados para distribuir cache de página acessadas que podem ser armazenadas na memória principal para melhorar a distribuição.

Para uma CDN ter um bom desempenho é necessário tomar cuidados para tornar o cabeçalho de entrega dos arquivo o menor possível, evitando por exemplo o uso de cookies no domínio do CDN, uma das vantagens é o aumento da pontuação em avaliações de SEO.

É muito importante observar a latência do servidor para determinado local. Por exemplo: O tempo de resposta de um servidor para o cliente localizado no brasil é 200ms e outro é 20ms, então o melhor servidor será o segundo. Para avaliar a latência dos servidores em diferentes locais existe um bando de sites que permite executar esses testes http://traceroute.org/

## A estrutura utilizando DNS com GeoIP

```
     [Servidor GeoDNS]
            | |
            | | --> [Servidor CDN 1] --|
            | |                        |
Cliente --> | | --> [Servidor CDN 2] --| --> [Servidor WEB]
            | |                        |
            | | --> [Servidor CDN 3] --|
            | |
```

O nó de conteúdo principal irá rodar uma mistura de Apache + PHP + MySQL por exemplo, os nós da ponta (servidores de entrega) poderão utilizar o [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) e o [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) para cache.

Para o servidor de DNS pode-se usar o [BIND9](http://www.bind9.net) junto com um [banco de dados GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/). Assim o servidor de DNS fará a distribuição por Geolocalização, porem uma requisição é redirecionada várias vezes até chegar ao servidor e voltar, o que pode fazer com que o IP do cliente não seja obtido corretamente. No entanto existe maneiras de contornar este problema, mas muitas vezes isso não causa grandes transtornos, a não ser que queira um servidor de CDN a nível de cidade.

## A estrutura utilizando DNS Anycast

A estrutura baseada em Anycast é um pouco mais complexa por estar em uma camada de rede mais baixa. O Anycast atribui um prefixo IP para vários servidores, enquanto o DNS comum tenta resolver um IP mais adequado para resposta, isso resulta em uma menor latência de resolução de nome.

Uma outra vantagem do Anycast é que serve tambem como balanceamento de carga, onde se um servidor mais próximo estiver fora do ar, ele automaticamente encaminha para outro.

```
         [Roteador]
Cliente --> | | --> [Servidor CDN 1] --|
                                       |
Cliente --> | | --> [Servidor CDN 2] --| --> [Servidor WEB]
                                       |
Cliente --> | | --> [Servidor CDN 3] --|
```

Ou seja, O cliente sempre receberá o mesmo IP e quando a rede receber a requisição, irá definir a melhor rota para atender. Não se trata de conectar diretamente a um servidor e sim a uma rede.

## Referências

- http://blog.unixy.net/2010/07/how-to-build-your-own-cdn-using-bind-geoip-nginx-and-varnish/
- http://blog.ebrandi.eti.br/2010/05/como-implementar-geodns-usando-o-bind/
- https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/
- https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/forwarding-visitors-real-ip/
- http://phix.me/geodns/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/516007/one-hostname-and-two-servers-in-different-countries
- https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/
- http://www.cloudvps.com/community/knowledge-base/how-does-a-cdn-work/
- https://www.psychz.net/client/kb/pt/learn-about-anycast-and-some-of-its-advantages-and-disadvantages.html
- http://ddiguru.com/blog/118-introduction-to-anycast-dns

Comment: Ótima explanação com os gráficos e ótimas referências, vou ler com calma cada uma.